# Oracle select inside an IF statement in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle

Coming from a sql server background, I am trying to get the grasp of oracle syntax.  I am trying to return some records back from a stored procedure but getting an error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_GetCustomers(username IN VARCHAR2)
AS

BEGIN

    if username = 'all' then
        select *
        from customers c;
    else
        select *
        from customers c
        where c.created_by = username;
    end if;

END;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing an INTO clause, but at this stage its better to use a FUNCTION to return values and a PROCEDURE to perform action.

Answer (score 0):

ORACLE doesn't create implicit cursors as a return parameter, you will have to explicitly declare a ref cursor and open it to return a pointer to a cursor, something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function SP_GetCustomers(username IN VARCHAR2) return sys_refcursor
AS
   ret_cursor sys_refcursor;
BEGIN

    if username = 'all' then
        open ret_cursor for
        'select *
        from customers c';
    else
        open ret_cursor for
        'select *
        from customers c
        where c.created_by = :username' using username ;
    end if;
  return ret_cursor;
END;
```

Comment: The cursor doesn't have to be dynamic. `open ret_cursor for select * from customers c where c.created_by = username` should do it.